# Writing ISO8859 data to MySQL in R (error:"could not run statement: Invalid utf8 character string")

Tags: mysql, r, utf-8, sas, iso-8859-1

I need to import an SAS Transfer File (.xpt) to MySQL.
Because I don't own SAS, I tried 
a) first importing the .xpt in R
b) then using dbWriteTable from the library RMySQL to create a table from the data frame.

The problem is that the data frame contains ISO8859 characters and MySQL (or dbWriteTable?) expects UTF-8.
(Detail: Precisely a degree character, which is B0 in ISO8859 and C2B0 in UTF8)
I receive the following output:

`dbWriteTable(con,"new_table",mydata,overwrite=T)
Fehler in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  could not run statement: Invalid utf8 character string: 'Hallo'`>

So I tried converting the data with iconv like iconv(mydata,"ISO8859-1","UTF8"), but it only seems to work vice-versa (it correctly converts UTF8 to ISO8859, but not the other way round).

Then I was trying a lot with

```
SET character_set_client = latin1;
SET character_set_results = latin1;
SET character_set_connection = latin1;
```

but without any luck.

Any help would be so appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround I want to share:

As iconv only works UTF8->ISO8859, this is no use, but you can:

- write the data frame to a temp file using fileEncoding="utf8"
- read it back
- then use dbWriteTable

  > write.table(mydata,file="tmp.txt", fileEncoding ="utf8")
  >   mydata_utf8 <- read.table(file="tmp.txt",encoding="utf8")
  >   dbWriteTable(con,"new_table",mydata_utf8,overwrite=T)